# Java WebSocketStompClient sending protobuf as byte[]

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, stomp, spring-websocket

Below is my WebSocketStompClient and protobuf example

```
message PushHeader {
double id = 1;
string first_name = 2;
string last_name = 3;
}


WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
    container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(10*1024*1024);
    container.setDefaultMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(10*1024 * 1024);

    WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient(container);
    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(webSocketClient);
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new ByteArrayMessageConverter());
    stompClient.setInboundMessageSizeLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Whenever i try to send a byte[] which contains a Protobuf(PushHeader.toByteArray()). I keep on getting this error below. I have noticed this only occurs when i fill in the id field. If i leave it blank then it goes through. int64 and doubles are not converting correctly i'm assuming.

Works

```
PushMessageProto.PushHeader r = PushMessageProto.PushHeader.newBuilder().setFirstName("df").setLastName("R").build();
```

Does Not Work

```
PushMessageProto.PushHeader r = PushMessageProto.PushHeader.newBuilder().setFirstName("d").setLastName("R").setId(1).build();
```

Does anyone know what direction i should go for?

org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompConversionException: Frame must be terminated with a null octet
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder.readPayload(StompDecoder.java:301) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder.decodeMessage(StompDecoder.java:139) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder.decode(StompDecoder.java:111) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.BufferingStompDecoder.decode(BufferingStompDecoder.java:133) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageFromClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:234) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:307) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:75) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:56) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:58) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.handleTextMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:110) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.access$000(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:42) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:81) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:78) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageText(WsFrameBase.java:375) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataText(WsFrameBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:275) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:116) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:55) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:194) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:184) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:95) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:650) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.3.jar:8.0.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]